# special character values getting trim down on parsing

Tags: javascript

I have special characters in the urlsearch params, so when parsing and getting the property value i am not getting the right value instead it breaks.

```js
var params = new URLSearchParams("a=2%15&b=balloon");

console.log(params.get('a')) // 2% => need to get 2%15
```

Comment: The `%15` in `a=2%15&b=balloon` has to be encoded if you want `%15` as literal value. Otherwise it is treated as a hex value.

Comment: `%` should be escaped as `%25` in that string because `%` is a control character. In javascript you can escape those using `encodeURIComponent` but you can't pass that whole string because it would encode also the ampersand

Comment: Where the string came from? Values needs to be encoded: `(new URLSearchParams("a="+encodeURIComponent("2%15")+"&b=balloon")).get("a")`